# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.aws/config'

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sdk

I create an app using react and node express. I have a problem when I run a docker image.
It has been built successfully. But when I run the image it couldn't go because of ./aws/config problem.

Docker build:

```
docker build -t test2 .
[+] Building 100.0s (11/11) FINISHED                                                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                        0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 210B                                                        0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14-alpine                           2.6s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                           4.1s
 => => transferring context: 3.35MB                                                         3.8s
 => CACHED [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:14-alpine@sha256:4aff4ba0da347e51561587eba037  0.0s
 => [2/5] COPY . /src                                                                      12.6s
 => [3/5] WORKDIR /src                                                                      0.0s
 => [4/5] RUN npm install                                                                  54.3s
 => [5/5] RUN npm run build                                                                17.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                      9.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                     9.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:d7b426fed3e0fc05947bdc966ad6924e15882b9607a4f89171b472cb6e3719  0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test2
```

Docker run :

```
docker container run -p 3000:3000 --rm test2
/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:133
        if (fileInfo.isConfig) throw err;
                               ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.aws/config'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:95:26)
    at parseFile (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:6:38)
    at IniLoader.loadFrom (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:72:25)
    at getRegion (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:131:32)
    at Config.region (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:186:18)
    at Config.set (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:600:39)
    at Config.<anonymous> (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:359:12)
    at Config.each (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:520:32) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/root/.aws/config'
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

COPY . /src

WORKDIR /src

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using aws sdk you have to load your configuration. Refer this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I downloaded aws-sdk in a package.json and my config file is under the usr/.aws/config (I'm using mac)

Comment: I updated the answer refer it. May be it will help you